# error in r.gwann$importance[1, , ] : object of type 's4' is not subsettable

Tags: r

I have code in R program :

```
r.gwann<-gwann(x_train=x_train[-s_test,],y_train=y_train[-s_test],w_train=dm[-s_test,-s_test],
                x_pred=x_train[s_test,],w_pred=dm[-s_test,s_test],
                nrHidden=5,batchSize=10,lr=0.1,optimizer="nesterov",cv_patience=9999,
                adaptive=F,kernel="gaussian", bandwidth = 0.39,
                bwSearch="goldenSection",bwMin=min(dm)/4, bwMax=max(dm)/4,
                threads=8)
print(paste("RMSE: ",gwann.fg$rmse))
print(paste("Iterations: ",gwann.fg$its))
print(paste("Bandwidth: ",gwann.fg$bw))
print(paste("RMSE: ",r.gwann$rmse))
print(paste("Iterations: ",r.gwann$its))
print(paste("Bandwidth: ",r.gwann$bw))

ypred<-cbind( r.gwann$predictions )
write.table(ypred,file="y pred_gwann.csv",sep=",")

pred=r.gwann[["predictions"]]
write.table(pred,file="pred.csv",sep=",")

#importance x1
s11<-cbind( err_diff=diag(r.gwann$importance[1,,]),data[,c("u","v")] )
write.table(s11,file="importance_x1.csv",sep=",")
```

And i got error "Error in r.gwann$importance[1, , ] :
object of type 'S4' is not subsettable" when run the last code in this line.

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi9l2.png)
Iam a newbie in R, It would be really great If I could get to know where I am going wrong and how to fix this error.

Thanks in advance!